# as const array but also specify type of element

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

What I am trying to achieve is construct array and union type of object keys.

```
type MyType = {
  key1:string;
  key2:string;
  key3:string;
  //...
}

const keysArray = ['key1', 'key2'] as const; // how do I specify that every element of this array is key of MyType, so I can not add there key that does not exist on MyType(for example key5555) and get good autocomplete

type SomeKyesUnion = typeof keysArray[number]; // 'key1' | 'key2'
```

tried the code example

Comment: Use the `satisfies` operator like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq9akm).  If that doesn't meet your needs let me know soon or else this will probably be closed as a duplicate of another `satisfies`-related question.